# Double buffering and printf

Tags: c, printf, buffer

I am having trouble with getting my other basic functions to work with double buffer.

for example in the code below, it runs and I can press either down or up to move my cursor, and when I press enter I am supposed to get a printf saying either making a new char, load, or goodbye.

It shows up for a split second but then it immediately disappears. In these situations rewind(stdin) and getchar(); solves this issue but for this code, nothing seems to work.

Please help.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "conioex.h"
#include "DblBuffer.h"

enum // 
{
    NEW_GAME = 20,
    LOAD,
    EXIT,
    MAX_NUM
};

void main (void)
{
    DblBuffer db;
    int Cursor_X, Cursor_Y; // cursorlocation
    bool Key_flag = false;  // pressandtrue
    int type = NEW_GAME;    // type
    Cursor_X = 20;
    Cursor_Y = 1;
    int flag = 1;
    while (flag)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            db.setCursorPos(20,i);
            db.write(" ");
        }
        db.setCursorPos(25,1);
        db.write("New Game\n");
        db.setCursorPos(25,2);
        db.write("Load\n");
        db.setCursorPos(25,3);
        db.write("Exit\n");

        if (inport(PK_DOWN))
        {
            if (Key_flag == false)
            {
                Cursor_Y = Cursor_Y + 1;
                type = type + 1;
                Key_flag = true;
            }
        }
        else if (inport(PK_UP))
        {
            if (Key_flag == false)
            {
                Cursor_Y = Cursor_Y - 1;
                type = type - 1;
                Key_flag = true;
            }
        }
        else if (inport(PK_ENTER))
        {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Key_flag = false;
        }

        if (Cursor_Y < 1)
        {
            Cursor_Y = 1;
        }
        if (Cursor_Y > 3)
        {
            Cursor_Y = 3;
        }

        if (type < NEW_GAME)
        {
            type = NEW_GAME;
        }
        if (type >= MAX_NUM)
        {
            type = MAX_NUM - 1;
        }

        db.setCursorPos(Cursor_X, Cursor_Y);
        db.write("→");
        db.swap();
    }

    if(type == NEW_GAME)
    {
        printf("making a new game");
    }
    if (type == LOAD)
    {
        printf("will load");
    }
    if (type == EXIT)
    {
        printf("goodbye");
    }

    rewind(stdin);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: What's this have to do with `C#`?

Comment: First of all, always end output using `printf` with a newline, to make sure the output is flushed (or explicitly [flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush) `stdout`). Secondly, calling `rewind` on a forward-only stream like `stdin` doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

As for your problem, by "then it immediately disappears" I assume that the console window disappears quickly?

That's because the program exits.

You need to flush the input buffer connected to `stdin` to remove all key presses you made (by *reading* from `stdin`) and then call `getchar` one extra time to get a a kind of confirmation that the user wants to exit.